# Linker error: undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_ecb'

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, openssl

I'm trying to compile openssl with cast support but I instead get this error:

```
SharedLibrary  : libcrypto.so
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto/evp/c_allc.o: In function `OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers':
~/testandroid/libssl/jni/crypto/evp/c_allc.c:143: undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_ecb'
~/testandroid/libssl/jni/crypto/evp/c_allc.c:144: undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_cfb64'
~/testandroid/libssl/jni/crypto/evp/c_allc.c:145: undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_ofb'
~/testandroid/libssl/jni/crypto/evp/c_allc.c:146: undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_cbc'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto/evp/e_old.o: In function `EVP_cast5_cfb':
~/testandroid/libssl/jni/crypto/evp/e_old.c:104: undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_cfb64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcrypto.so] Error 1
```

EVP_cast5_ecb and friends are all defined in ~/testandroid/libssl/jni/crypto/evp/evp.h and in ~/testandroid/libssl/jni/include/evp.h

```
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_CAST
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_cast5_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_cast5_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_cast5_cfb64(void);
# define EVP_cast5_cfb EVP_cast5_cfb64
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_cast5_ofb(void);
#endif
```

In crypto/Android.mk

```
local_src_files := \
evp/c_allc.c \
evp/e_old.c \
# And a whole bunch of other c files 

local_c_includes := \
$(APP_PROJECT_PATH) \
$(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/crypto/asn1 \
$(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/crypto/evp \ # evp.h is located here
$(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/include \
$(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/include/openssl # Another evp.h is also located here

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../android-config.mk

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)
    LOCAL_NDK_VERSION := 5
    LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 9
    # Use the NDK prebuilt libz and libdl.
    LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -lz -ldl
else
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libz libdl
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(local_src_files)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += $(local_c_flags)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(local_c_includes)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE:= libcrypto
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm probably missing something very trivial here, since I'm new to Android and C in general, so be nice :)

EDIT: I saw that there is a Makefile for cast. I'm guessing there is a whole load of linking magic going on at the very bottom of the original Makefile. How would I do something equivalent for Android?

```
#
# OpenSSL/crypto/cast/Makefile
#

DIR=    cast
TOP=    ../..
CC=         cc
CPP=    $(CC) -E
INCLUDES=
CFLAG=-g
MAKEFILE=   Makefile
AR=     ar r

CAST_ENC=c_enc.o

CFLAGS= $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAG)
ASFLAGS= $(INCLUDES) $(ASFLAG)
AFLAGS= $(ASFLAGS)

GENERAL=Makefile
TEST=casttest.c
APPS=

LIB=$(TOP)/libcrypto.a
LIBSRC=c_skey.c c_ecb.c c_enc.c c_cfb64.c c_ofb64.c 
LIBOBJ=c_skey.o c_ecb.o $(CAST_ENC) c_cfb64.o c_ofb64.o

SRC= $(LIBSRC)

EXHEADER= cast.h
HEADER= cast_s.h cast_lcl.h $(EXHEADER)

ALL=    $(GENERAL) $(SRC) $(HEADER)

top:
(cd ../..; $(MAKE) DIRS=crypto SDIRS=$(DIR) sub_all)

all:    lib

lib:    $(LIBOBJ)
            $(AR) $(LIB) $(LIBOBJ)
        $(RANLIB) $(LIB) || echo Never mind.
        @touch lib

cast-586.s: asm/cast-586.pl ../perlasm/x86asm.pl ../perlasm/cbc.pl
$(PERL) asm/cast-586.pl $(PERLASM_SCHEME) $(CLAGS) $(PROCESSOR) > $@

files:
$(PERL) $(TOP)/util/files.pl Makefile >> $(TOP)/MINFO

links:
@$(PERL) $(TOP)/util/mklink.pl ../../include/openssl $(EXHEADER)
@$(PERL) $(TOP)/util/mklink.pl ../../test $(TEST)
@$(PERL) $(TOP)/util/mklink.pl ../../apps $(APPS)

install:
@[ -n "$(INSTALLTOP)" ] # should be set by top Makefile...
@headerlist="$(EXHEADER)"; for i in $$headerlist ; \
do  \
(cp $$i $(INSTALL_PREFIX)$(INSTALLTOP)/include/openssl/$$i; \
chmod 644 $(INSTALL_PREFIX)$(INSTALLTOP)/include/openssl/$$i ); \
done;

tags:
ctags $(SRC)

tests:

lint:
lint -DLINT $(INCLUDES) $(SRC)>fluff

depend:
@[ -n "$(MAKEDEPEND)" ] # should be set by upper Makefile...
$(MAKEDEPEND) -- $(CFLAG) $(INCLUDES) $(DEPFLAG) -- $(PROGS) $(LIBSRC)

dclean:
$(PERL) -pe 'if (/^# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE/) {print; exit(0);}' $(MAKEFILE) >Makefile.new
mv -f Makefile.new $(MAKEFILE)

clean:
rm -f *.s *.o *.obj lib tags core .pure .nfs* *.old *.bak fluff

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend depends on it.

c_cfb64.o: ../../e_os.h ../../include/openssl/cast.h
c_cfb64.o: ../../include/openssl/e_os2.h ../../include/openssl/opensslconf.h
c_cfb64.o: c_cfb64.c cast_lcl.h
c_ecb.o: ../../e_os.h ../../include/openssl/cast.h
c_ecb.o: ../../include/openssl/e_os2.h ../../include/openssl/opensslconf.h
c_ecb.o: ../../include/openssl/opensslv.h c_ecb.c cast_lcl.h
c_enc.o: ../../e_os.h ../../include/openssl/cast.h
c_enc.o: ../../include/openssl/e_os2.h ../../include/openssl/opensslconf.h
c_enc.o: c_enc.c cast_lcl.h
c_ofb64.o: ../../e_os.h ../../include/openssl/cast.h
c_ofb64.o: ../../include/openssl/e_os2.h ../../include/openssl/opensslconf.h
c_ofb64.o: c_ofb64.c cast_lcl.h
c_skey.o: ../../e_os.h ../../include/openssl/cast.h
c_skey.o: ../../include/openssl/e_os2.h ../../include/openssl/opensslconf.h
c_skey.o: c_skey.c cast_lcl.h cast_s.h
```

Comment: Errors like `undefined reference to...` are linker errors. Thus it is not important that `evp.h` is there (it missing would lead to a compiler failure). Instead, after the object is compiled, the linker cannot find the object which contains these functions. Instead of "include" (which is for headers) you need either library paths or object files. Maybe search in that direction.

Comment: Hi, see my edit above. I think I might have found something regarding the object files..

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but what seems interesting here is the `lib` target, especially all the variables in `$(LIBOBJ)`. Here the it seems the linking happens. As a starting point you could try this: Look in which object the implementation is (e.g. `c_enc.o`) and then give that to the linker when compiling your other objects. You might need to read up on the theory here.

Comment: Pass the `V=1` option to `ndk-build` if you aren't already doing that, to give you greater insight into what's going on.